# Why does Composer (PHP) allow me to specify "ext-json" but not other extensions like "ext-gmp" during "composer require"?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-extension

When I use Composer to run `composer require ext-gmp`, without a `composer.json` file or `composer.lock` file in the current directory, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a matching version of package ext-gmp. Check the package spelling,
your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which
matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

This makes sense to me based on my understanding of PHP extensions and Composer so far. You wouldn't use Composer to install extensions. They're installed globally on the system. Composer is only for PHP packages.

However, I noticed that if I repeat the previous steps and instead run `composer require ext-json`, I get the following output:

```
./composer.json has been created
Running composer update ext-json
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
No installed packages - skipping audit.
```

And at that point, I have a `composer.json` file that looks like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "ext-json": "*"
    }
}
```

And I have a `composer.lock` file that looks like this:

```json
{
    "_readme": [
        "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
        "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies",
        "This file is @generated automatically"
    ],
    "content-hash": "93d2b466348eca908189088d43f9fb1a",
    "packages": [],
    "packages-dev": [],
    "aliases": [],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "stability-flags": [],
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "prefer-lowest": false,
    "platform": {
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "platform-dev": [],
    "plugin-api-version": "2.3.0"
}
```

I find this strange. It looks like Composer created entries in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` that are correct for when you want to indicate that your project requires the `ext-json` installed on the system. So far, I haven't experimented with other extensions besides `ext-json` and `ext-gmp` to uncover more extensions that Composer will allow you to notate in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` as system requirements, like for `ext-json`.

What's special about `ext-json` that makes it work this way with Composer?

When I searched for whether the question was already answered, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219962/composer-require-ext-zip-fails), where the asker wanted to know why Composer could not install an extension for them. This is different from my situation. Here, I understand that Composer is not the tool one would use to install a PHP extension, and therefore I understand what the error message from `composer require ext-gmp` is telling me. But I want to know why Composer makes an exception for `ext-json` and behaves differently for it.

System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
$ php --version
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2023 22:56:18) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ composer --version
Composer version 2.5.1 2022-12-22 15:33:54
```

Comment: Composer can't install extensions. It probably just says if the extension is installed already when you try do do so. `ext-json` is generally always present in PHP it's hard not to have it

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'd have to set up other systems or play around with some Docker containers to put together a PHP installation that lacks the `ext-json` extension if I wanted to see this in action. But I can also take your word for it. When I look at the Composer docs, they have a section about "platform packages" which is the only part of the docs that mention the phrase "ext-" (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages). So, maybe they haven't documented this behavior I witnessed?

Comment: I just tried something myself to confirm what you described. You're exactly right. I'm on Ubuntu, so the right command for my particular version of PHP to install the extension was `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gmp`. I ran that, then ran `php -m | grep gmp` and noted that then I saw `gmp` as the output of that command for the first time. And then, when I ran `composer require ext-gmp`, I didn't get the error and the extension was notated in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` just like `ext-json` was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the ext-json extension compared to other extensions that allows it to be listed in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` whereas others aren't.

I was unaware that `composer require` does more than just manage your local project. It also checks your system while you're using it to add a dependency. In my case, when I ran `composer require ext-json`, it checked my system to see whether I already had the extension installed. Because I did, it didn't error out and it continued to fulfill its local project management task (editing `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to add it). But, when I ran `composer require ext-gmp`, it saw that I did not already have that extension installed, and it errored out early without doing anything related to local project management.

I didn't actually need this system checking functionality, but if I did, the solution would have been to install the extension. I was able to test this by running `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gmp`. After that, running `composer require ext-gmp` did not error out and resulted in my `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files being edited to include it in the list of extensions required.

So, in summary, my solution involved now understanding that Composer does at least two types of tasks:

- Allows you to specify a project's dependencies and system requirements in terms of required PHP version and extensions
- Checks the system you happen to be working on while you attempt to change your project's system requirements to see if that system would fulfill the new requirements, at least when it comes to extensions

And I have to keep this 2nd point in mind as I develop because I'm deploying PHP code to a cloud platform, so my computer's PHP installation has nothing to do with the PHP installation that will ultimately be running my project's code.

Answer (score 0):

there is two concepts of adding functionality to your php application

- install package via composer. this could be any library or framework written in PHP
- extand functionality of PHP itself by installing extension

PHP is written in C and have ability to extand core language functionality. this extensions usually is written in C and you can count them as "plugin" or "module" for language. you neeed to recompile PHP to make them work

there are some extensions out of the box in php - like json extension you mentioned. it allows php to work with jsons
and there are many more. for example to make PHP work with images or zip files. or to use debugger (xdebug - you should definetly try it!)

composer is php packages manager. it can't change PHP itself. so you cant add extensions via composer. only PHP packages

but composer can verify that you PHP has extensions your application needs. this is line `"ext-json": "*"` will tell composer to warn you if this extension is missing in your PHP. but `ext-json` is already in any modern PHP version. so this check is useless

i never tried `ext-gmp` but i guess it's not included in core PHP. so you should install it additionally. and add `"require": "ext-gmp"` just to be sure you or your coworkers will not forget install that extension on their own

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I don't think it's relevant to my question though. I was able to learn about PHP extensions and how Composer can be used to both install PHP packages and list extension requirements. My question was about why those two extensions were treated differently when I was running the `composer require` command. I wanted to know if there was something special about the `ext-json` extension compared to others.